# Parsing concrete syntax in Scheme

Tags: parsing, scheme

I wrote a procedure that gets a valid prefix list for subtraction (e.g, "(- 6 5)" for what we know as "6-5"). Here is my code:

```
(define parse-diff-list
(lambda (datum)
(cond
  ((number? datum) (const-exp datum))  ;; if datum is a number, return const-exp
  ((pair? datum)                       ;; if datum is a pair:
    (let ((sym (car datum)))                ;; let sym be the first of the pair
      (cond
      ((eqv? sym '-)                          ;; if sym is minus:
       (let ((lst1 (parse-diff-list (cdr datum)))) ;; parse second element of subtraction
         (let ((lst2 (parse-diff-list (cdr lst1))))  ;; parse first element of subtraction
           (cons (diff-exp (car lst1) (car lst2)) (cdr lst2))))) ;; "perform" the subtraction
      ((number? sym)                         ;; if sym is number:
       (cons (const-exp sym) (cdr datum)))   ;; return const-exp with the remainder of the list, yet to be processed
      (else (eopl:error 'parse-diff-list "bad prefix-expression, expected - ~s" sym)))))
  (eopl:error 'parse-diff-list "bad prefix-expression ~s" datum))))

(define parse-prefix
  (lambda (lst)
    (car (parse-diff-list lst))))
```

It works fine logically, but I don't understand the logic of the indentation in printing. For the input:

> (parse-prefix '(- - 1 2 - 3 - 4 5))

It prints:

```
#(struct:diff-exp
  #(struct:diff-exp #(struct:const-exp 1) #(struct:const-exp 2))
  #(struct:diff-exp #(struct:const-exp 3) #(struct:diff-exp #(struct:const-exp 4) #(struct:const-exp 5)))
```

While I would want the following print style:

```
  #(struct:diff-exp
    #(struct:diff-exp 
      #(struct:const-exp 1) 
      #(struct:const-exp 2))
    #(struct:diff-exp 
      #(struct:const-exp 3) 
      #(struct:diff-exp 
        #(struct:const-exp 4) 
        #(struct:const-exp 5)))
```

It's more than a petty question for me, as it does create indentations but I don't know how it does it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `racket/pretty` the pretty printing library.

In particular note the parameter `(pretty-print-columns)` which
you can set like this:

```
`(pretty-print-columns 40)`
```

in order to avoid long lines.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pretty-print.html

(I am guessing you are using DrRacket based on the way the structures are printing)

Comment: Than's a possible idea (indeed using DrRacket), but what causes it to perform the indentations now (without me using any specific printing style)?